# Term reference field lists the terms for all the languages

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, forms, i18n-l10n

What I meant is that I have the i18n module installed and configured for content and taxonomies, this is what I need

I have a taxonomy called "Colors" I have translated all the terms of this taxonomy from spanish to english

I have a term reference field in a content type that points to the taxonomy "Colors"

While I create the the node of that content type and try to select a color, the select list shows me all the colors in english and spanish, is there a way of update that term reference select list to show only the terms for the selected language for that node?

Check the image and you will understand what I mean
[image]

If you check the image I selected in the list as language spanish, but in the color checkboxes it shows me all the terms in both languages (English & Spanish)

How to show the terms depending of the selected language while creating the node?

This is the image of the translated and original taxonomy terms in Spanish and English
[image]

Comment: What `Translation mode` you have selected for "Colors"? Did you translate the term or you created seperate term for each language?

Comment: In the edit page of the taxonomy I checked "Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated."

Comment: Then can you post your term list and edit page screenshot

Comment: when you edit a term there will be a select box called **Language**, can you tell me what value you have for each term.

Comment: ok I added the the image of the taxonomy term list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting `Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized` as the **Translation mode**, after that remove the terms that you added separately for Spanish language and edit each term that are there in English and translate it to Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want different colors for each languages, set "Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated." in the vocabolary terms, after check in admin/config/regional/i18n/select -> Select taxonomy terms by language