# Why my taxonomy term list in content is not using node languages prefererence

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual website, in which I activated the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module and every related modules.

I have a taxonomy vocabulary **Colors**.

When I create or edit a content, all my colors are displayed. What I mean is, even if my node are in English, I saw every colors (English and French).

Is there a way to displayed my color based on node languages preference?

Comment: I have answered a similar question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/120763/17003, check whether it helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm using the second method (Translate). My concern by using the Localize is that I not only have the name and description to translate, I have more fields. Other things, I want to be able to specify the url alias for each languages and localize do not permit that.

Comment: Can you make sure that language is selected for each term, and it is not `Language neutral`

Comment: Thanks wolverine, it was the problem. But for a reason that I didn't understand, when I try to translate my term with an image, the language field return back to Language Neutral. I opened an new question for that http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121119/taxonomy-with-image-field-is-not-translating

Answer (score 0):

Check the "translation mode" that you've specified within admin/structure/taxonomy/colors/edit (whereas "colors" is the name of your specific category): by default that is set to "Localize", though it should be set to "translate".

After changing this value, be aware that you then also have to:

- enter a translated value for each of the tags and
- revisit any of the existing nodes that are already using the specific taxonomy, so that they use the (translated) term that corresponds to the language of the node.