# taxonomy with image field is not translating

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a taxonomy term with an image field in it.

The problem is when I try to translate the taxonomy term and choose an image, the term is not translated and the language is set back to Language Neutral on save action.

Here is the message who came up when I hit the save button

```
Created new term testtttttt.
You are not authorized to access this page.
```

It's only happened when I fill the Image field, otherwise the taxonomy is translated correctly.

It's seem to be a new bug in drupal 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2227181

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary solution, when you add the image don't upload it, just select it and save the term, it will translate correctly.

I will update the answer once I find why it is not working when the image is uploaded first.

**Update :** The problem is that when you upload the image the `$form` gets cached without the translation details. Use the following code as workaround.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
   if(($form_id=='taxonomy_form_term') && (!isset($form_state['triggering_element']) || $form_state['triggering_element']['#id']!='edit-delete')){
       $form['#after_build'][] = 'MYMODULE_after_build';
}

function MYMODULE_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
     if(!isset($form_state['storage']['rebuilding'])){
        $form_state['storage']['rebuilding']=TRUE;

     }
     else{
        $form_state['no_cache']=TRUE; 
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot wolverine, I'll continue to find the reason why too.

Comment: @Jean-Francois Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

I tried wolverine's answer but it didn't worked for me, it caused error "#build_id not defined" so I changed it a little, I don't know if it's right solution but it worked for me.

Add only this code in your module:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if (($form_id == 'taxonomy_form_term') && (!isset($form_state['triggering_element']) || $form_state['triggering_element']['#id'] != 'edit-delete')) {
        if (!isset($form_state['storage']['rebuilding'])) {
            $form_state['storage']['rebuilding'] = TRUE;

        } else {
            $form_state['no_cache'] = TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it's helpful for someone.